# List.addAll performance when the Collection to add is empty

Tags: java, performance, arraylist

In Java, given two ArrayLists, is it more performing to do:

```java
if (!list2.isEmpty()) {
    list1.addAll(0, list2);
}
```

or directly

```java
list1.addAll(0, list2);
```

letting the addAll method handle the optionally empty list?

Let's say the number of cases where the second list is empty is about two thirds of the total use cases.

Comment: Hard to say. What exact Java version, which vendor, what CPU, which operating system, which Collection you want to add to...

Comment: Don't try to optimise code early. It works either way and it's not worth the effort adding the `if` check as you would be unlikely to notice the difference compared to, say, removing a single unnecessary disc access made by your application or ensuring that `ArrayList` is pre-sized closer to the desired length before the adds.

Comment: Agree with DuncG.  Checking isEmpty() will either provide no benefit, or will provide a benefit too small to measure.  Clean code is more important than saving a few nanoseconds.

Comment: @DuncG thanks, I was actually trying to make sense of such an if in a piece of code not made by me and I wanted to make sure removing it wouldn't matter.

Answer (score -3):

Empty ok for addAll method. but null is not. Please check null before do it.

`if(list1 != null && list2 != null) { list1.addAll(0, list2); }`

Comment: Yeah I know it's not null safe, but in my actual code I know those two lists can't be null at that point. My question was really about the performance of having that if or not.

Comment: The answer doesn't address the question topic